# How to scale text when drawing to canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, css-transforms

I am scaling text using CSS transform scale eg

```
transform: scale(2, 4);
fontSize: 20px // do I need to include fontSize?
```

I also need to draw the same text on a canvas element

```
function draw() {
  const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = '20px serif';
  ctx.fillText('Hello world', 10, 50);
}
```

How should I scale the text in the above js function? I've hardcoded the font size `20px` but how would I use the scale values of `2` and `4`?

Comment: Canvas is not affected by `font-size` css property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the context of the canvas to have scaling by calling the context's scale function.

Here's an example:

```js
function draw() {
  const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = '20px serif';
  ctx.scale(2, 4);
  ctx.fillText('Hello world', 10, 50);
}
window.onload = draw;
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```

Don't forget to reset the scale when you've finished drawing the text.